# This certificate lacks a "hosts" field. This makes it unsuitable for websites

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

when I execute this command to generate kubernetes certificate:

```
cfssl gencert -ca=ca.pem -ca-key=ca-key.pem \
-config=ca-config.json \
-profile=kubernetes \
kubernetes-csr.json | cfssljson -bare kubernetes
```

Why the cfssl took shows:

```
[root@iZuf63refzweg1d9dh94t8Z ssl]# cfssl gencert -ca=ca.pem -ca-key=ca-key.pem \
> -config=ca-config.json \
> -profile=kubernetes \
> kubernetes-csr.json | cfssljson -bare kubernetes
2019/08/25 20:02:12 [INFO] generate received request
2019/08/25 20:02:12 [INFO] received CSR
2019/08/25 20:02:12 [INFO] generating key: rsa-2048
2019/08/25 20:02:13 [INFO] encoded CSR
2019/08/25 20:02:13 [INFO] signed certificate with serial number 540759253485135214776496461610290604881680785507
2019/08/25 20:02:13 [WARNING] This certificate lacks a "hosts" field. This makes it unsuitable for
websites. For more information see the Baseline Requirements for the Issuance and Management
of Publicly-Trusted Certificates, v.1.1.6, from the CA/Browser Forum (https://cabforum.org);
specifically, section 10.2.3 ("Information Requirements").
```

this is my kubernetes(kubernetes-csr.json) config:

```
{
    "CN": "kubernetes",
    "hosts": [
      "127.0.0.1",
      "172.19.104.230",
      "172.19.150.82",
      "172.19.104.231"
    ],
    "key": {
        "algo": "rsa",
        "size": 2048
    },
    "names": [
        {
            "C": "CN",
            "ST": "BeiJing",
            "L": "BeiJing",
            "O": "k8s",
            "OU": "System"
        }
    ]
}
```

obviously it contains hosts field. I am using cfssl version 1.2 .Is this a bug?

Comment: Looks like this is https://github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/issues/717. I suggest you try a newer version of cfssl. (1.2 is nearly 2 1/2 years old...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update cfssl version from v1.2 to v1.3.4(latest version):

```
go get -u github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/cmd/cfssl
```